# Error resolving FQBN (Fully Qualified Board Name)

Tags: m5stack

In Arduino IDE, I get this error "Error resolving FQBN: getting", when compiling a sketch. Can anyone help me get around this problem?

I am using the Arduino IDE. I have installed the M5Stack official 2.0.5-1.0 boards in Board Manager and the STAMP-PICO 0.0.2 library in Library Manager.

I get the following Compile error with ALL sketches, even the STAMP-PICO Basics IO example sketch.

"Error resolving FQBN: getting Error compiling for board STAMP-PICO."

Strangely ... in Arduino IDE v2.0.3, on the same computer using the same libraries and boards, the sketch compiles ok.

Sounds like something specific to Arduino IDE v1

Comment: @MG1 What board exactly do you have?

Answer (score 3):

OK - I resolved the issue, myself.

The Boards Manager installations became confused, probably because I was using both Arduino 1.8.19 and Arduino IDE 2.0.3 on the same computer.

Somehow, the folder ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/m5stack/hardware/esp32/ contained more than one version of the esp32 board libraries, v2.0.5 as well as v2.0.5-1.0 and c2.0.5+1.0.

My fix involved uninstalling the M5 esp32 board library altogether and making sure that all sub-folder versions had been deleted too. Then, reinstalling the latest board version and restarting the Arduino IDE app.